# How to use picture as submit button to trigger php function

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am looking for a better way to submit a form using a picture as submit button.

Below code is working, but it is not looking very smooth. It still has the hover effect from the `type=submit` and it dosnt look good on mobile as well.

Does someone have an idea, for a better way to use a picture to trigger this function, and still send the hidden values. Maybe something like`onclick`, IDK ?

Post trigger:

```
if (isset($_POST['unfollow'])) {
 unfollow_user();
 header("Refresh:0");
}
```

Form:

```
echo "
 <form action='' method='post'>
 <input type='hidden' name='user_id' value='".$user_id."'/>
 <input type='hidden' name='other_user_id' value='".$latesttipusers['id']."'/>
 <button type='submit' name='unfollow' class='follow'><img class='floatright 
 follow_img_small' src='img/following_da_small.png'></button>
 </form>"; }
```

Submit triggers this functions

```
function unfollow_user(){
global $mysql_connect;

$my_user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
$follow_other_user_id = $_POST['other_user_id'];
$sql_query = "DELETE FROM tb_follow WHERE user_id = '$my_user_id' AND 
follow_user_id = '$follow_other_user_id'";
$result = mysqli_query($mysql_connect, $sql_query);
}
```

CSS

```
.follow_img_small {
height: 25px;
margin-right: -25px;
margin-top: -10px;
}

.follow_img:hover{
opacity: 0.7;
}
```

Comment: There was ye olde skool `<input type="image" ... />` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/image)

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: There's no need to put an image literally inside the `<button>` tag, instead set the background of the button to be the image with the `background-image: url(...)` style. Keep in mind that to look good on mobile means you need `@2x` or `@3x` versions to handle high-DPI screens as used on phones or your image will look super chunky at the default desktop 72DPI.

Comment: You can target the button and override any styles that it already has. If you want to target the hover effects particularly on type=submit, use `.follow[type="submit"]:hover{...}`.

Comment: This is also nothing to do with PHP or MySQL or JavaScript. You should edit your question to remove those tags and code.

Comment: @tadman can you tell me how to do this in example above? I am new to coding, so trying to learn.

I will try with the background image instead.

miken32 what will you call (mysqli_query)  if is not mysql and this (if (isset($_POST['unfollow'])) {) if it is not php ? I will give you javascript, but as suggest in description that I am open for onclick solutions, which is why I added it.

Comment: You're asking about the appearance of a button in your HTML. What happens when you click the button is of no consequence to this question.

Comment: There's a number of links there on how to use `bind_param` correctly. That's the key to writing safe queries.

Answer (score 0):

As comments suggest you should put the image as background to the button (and leave it as type:submit).

So, instead of this line:

```
<button type='submit' name='unfollow' class='follow'><img class='floatright 
 follow_img_small' src='img/following_da_small.png'></button>
```

you should write:

```
<button type='submit' name='unfollow' class='follow'><span>Submit Me</span></button>
```

And in your CSS style it like that (relying on you css for the img):

```
button.follow { width: auto; height: 25px; background: url(img/following_da_small.png) no-repeat; background-size: cover; }
button.follow span {visibility: hidden; /* OR: opacity: 0; this is just for accessibility purpose */ }
```

Hope it solve it, and good luck!

Answer (score -1):

As all of the comments say, use the HTML Form Element:

```
<input type="image" id="submit" src="" />
```

[<input type="image" /> - Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/image)

If you use the method above, simply use  jQuery to trigger the submit:

```
$("#submit").on("click", function () {
     $("form").trigger("submit");
});
```

You could also use CSS `background-image: url();` on the `button` element or the `input[type=submit]` button element, but I recommend the above, because it will look better on most platforms.

Hope this helps!

Comment: but how can I get this image to likewise be type='submit' ?

Comment: cause when I change it to: <input type='image' src='img/following_da_small.png' name='unfollow' class='floatright follow_img_small'/>  nothing happens when I choose it.